# como puedo insertar dos insert en un trigger

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

como puedo hacer dos insert en un trigger intente eso pero no me anda, si pongo un solo insert si jala pero en phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_alumnos AFTER INSERT ON Alumnos
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Procesos VALUES (new.id,1,1)
    INSERT INTO Validar_residencia VALUES (new.id,0,'sin observaciones')
END
```

Comment: Te faltan los `;` en cada inserción

Comment: Ya habia intentado eso y aun asi no me deja

Comment: ¿Qué error te manda?

Comment: For the right syntax to use near ' ' al line3

Comment: repito el comentario de arriba, faltan los ;, y esta mal una de las lineas del query, eso es lo que te dice el error. andan los dos insert por separado?

Comment: si pongo esto si me jala

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER update_alumnos AFTER INSERT ON Alumnos
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO Procesos VALUES (new.id,1,1)

Comment: al parecer es problema del begin

Comment: pero no me deja poner el otro insert

Comment: el begin esta bien (aunque podes escribir 2 triggers para la tabla si queres). la pregunta anterior fue si el segundo insert anda..

Comment: los dos por separado andan

Comment: pero porque no se puede?

Comment: pq faltan los punto y coma!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo solucione al parecer tenia que poner un delimitador

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER update_alumnos AFTER INSERT ON Alumnos
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO Procesos VALUES (new.id,1,1);
INSERT INTO Validar_residencia VALUES (new.id,0,'sin observaciones');
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Intenta cambiando tu sentencia de esta forma:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER update_alumnos AFTER INSERT ON Alumnos
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Procesos VALUES (new.id,1,1);
    INSERT INTO Validar_residencia VALUES (new.id,0,'sin observaciones');
END;
|
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Leí tu código y realmente lo que falta es un **punto y coma** (" **;** ") al final de cada uno de los

**INSERT INTO**.

Ejemplo:

```
 INSERT INTO Procesos VALUES (new.id,1,1) ;
 INSERT INTO Validar_residencia VALUES (new.id,0,'sin observaciones') ;
```