# SQL trigger para insertar multiples registros después de un insert

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, trigger

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
   Tabla: Insumos
   Columnas:
   idInsumo
   nombreIns
   descripcionIns
   unidadIns
   presentacionIns
   fechaCadIns
   marcaIns
```

Y la siguiente tabla UMAP:

```
   Tabla: UMAP
   Columnas:
   idUmap
   nombreUmap
   ubicacionUmap
   cuerpoUmap
   tramo_idTramo
   umap_idDelegacion
```

Y tengo esta tabla que conecta a ambas:

```
   Tabla: InventarioInsumos
   Columnas:
   idInventarioIns
   cantidadIns
   ins_idumap
   ins_idinsumo
```

Y estoy intentando crear un trigger en la tabla InventarioInsumos que haga lo siguiente:

Despues de que se ha insertado un registro nuevo en la tabla Insumos, se haga el registro en la tabla InventarioInsumos, en la que se creen la misma cantidad de registros que los que hay en la tabla UMAP, donde:

```
    idInventarioIns = este es valor autoincrementable
    cantidadIns = este se debe de generar en 0
    ins_idumap = este id debe de ser el de la tabla UMAP idUmap
    ins_idinsumo = este id debe de ser el id del insumo recien creado
```

Sin embargo no estoy muy familiarizado con el uso de triggers y este problema me esta causando un gran dolor de cabeza, espero me puedan mostrar el camino a seguir

Answer (score 1):

No muestras el error ni tampoco entiendo exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer, voy a suponer que deseas ejecutar múltiples instrucciones en un **trigger**, y para esto es necesario que este dentro de un bloque **BEGIN - END**, a continuación te explico la estructura en cuestión con un ejemplo especifico para MySQL: (No olvidar el ";" por cada sentencia SQL)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `I_email` BEFORE INSERT ON `testudiantes` 

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

INSERT INTO tasistencia(email) VALUES (NEW.email);
INSERT INTO thorarios(email) VALUES (NEW.email);

END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

A demás de esto, no olvides que no se pueden crear mas de dos **triggers** del mismo tipo en la misma tabla, o sea que solo puede haber un **INSERT BEFORE**, un solo **INSERT AFTER** , etc en la misma *tabla*.

**Citas:**

[Uso de triggers](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76292/como-puedo-insertar-dos-insert-en-un-trigger/76303#76303)

Answer (score -1):

Siguiendo lo que dice el compañero, yo utilizaría un **AFTER INSERT**, podes leer más aquí: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/

Sería bueno saber que Gestor de Base de Datos estás utilizando.

Saludos!